# Kivy FileChooser: how do I list Files only and not Directories?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, kivy, filechooser

I created a FileChooser (below) in Kivy that displays directories and not files.  But, how do I create a FileChooser in Kivy that will display *only files and not directories*.

My KV code:

```
FileChooserListView:
    id: MTDcontainer
    size_hint_y: .87
    size_hint_x: .95
    halign: "left"
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .60}
    on_selection: app.MTDirWasChosen_callback(args)
    path: "."
    filters: [lambda folder, filename: not filename.endswith('')]   #display dirs only
    dirselect: True
...
```

Comment: If you don't display directories, how will you navigate to the files that you want?

Comment: I don't want the user to navigate away from the path I send to FileChooser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using some attributes of the `FileChooser` along with a custom filter. First, change your `path` attribute to `rootpath` instead. That eliminates the `..` entry that normally is displayed. Then you can add a method that filters out directories, but you must also add the `filter_dirs: True` in order for the filter to be applied to folders. Here is a modified version of your `kv` that does that:

```
FileChooserListView:
    id: MTDcontainer
    size_hint_y: .87
    size_hint_x: .95
    halign: "left"
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .60}
    on_selection: app.MTDirWasChosen_callback(args)
    rootpath: "."
    filters: [app.file_filter]
    filter_dirs: True
```

And the `file_filter()` method in the `App` is just:

```
def file_filter(self, folder, file):
    return not os.path.isdir(file)
```